# Check if running in a 32 or 64 bit machine

Tags: linux

I would like to do a check like

```
if system($(uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/') == 64
    Plug 'valloric/youcompleteme', { 'do': './install.py --all' }
else
    Plug 'valloric/youcompleteme', { 'do': './install.py --clang-complete --system-libclang --omnisharp-completer --gocode-completer --tern-completer --racer-completer' }
endif
```

Comment: Welcome to this site @Arturo. We value well written questions which show efforts to solve the problem first. Here your expression doesn't have matching brackets and you don't describe which error you get. Please edit your question to address these problems.

Comment: What do you need the check for? If it's to see if 64 Numbers are supported you might use `has('num64')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're looking for is the following:

```
if system('uname -m | grep 64') == 0
    echo '64 bit system'
else
    echo '32 bit system'
endif
```

Your call to system `system($(uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/')` doesn't have a matching number of brackets.

Also you don't need to use the `$(...)` syntax since `system()` take a string to execute as parameter.

Finally you don't need to use `sed`, `grep` is enough to detect the presence of a substring in a string.

Comment: I wonder if `has('num64')` is the same?

Comment: You could also use `uname -p` and not have to bother with `grep` or 'sed` at all. That would make the test `if system('uname -p') == "x86_64\n"`. Note that the output of `system()` generally includes a terminating newline.

Comment: @garyjohn You're right: I used the `grep` version to avoid using the new line character in the condition but using one command instead of two is indeed better :)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't know. The doc says `64-bit Number support` but I guess you can compile Vim with this flag on a 32 bit system? I'll try to make some test when I have more time.